# Which choice is better for generating equals() and hashCode() methods in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, equals, lombok, hashcode

I create `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in each Hibernate entity (if there is no inheritance) in my Java app. However, I am a little bit confused and wanted to be sure if I define it properly. Could you please clarify the following issues?

1. In IntelliJ, when I use the "Generate" feature (via Alt + Insert), there are some templates like IntelliJ Default, Java 7+, etc. Which template should I use?
2. When using the "Generate" feature, which field should I include in my `equals() and hashCode()` methods of the following entity?

   ```
   @Entity
   public class User {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;

       private String name;

       @Column(unique = true)
       private String email;

       // getter, setter, constructor...
   }
   ```
3. Should I use annotation for simple and easy usage like `@EqualsAndHashCode`? Or is it not flexible and should I prefer implementing explicitly?

Comment: I could write an answer, but [this blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) explains what you need to do. To answer your question neither of what you proposed.

Comment: Actually I read that blog, but not being clarified about some points. On the other hand, what do you mean with "neither of what I proposed"? I have 3 questions but you seem to be mix all of them.

Comment: Don;'t generate as that includes all fields (hence 1 and 2 don't dop it) 3 is using lombok if you only have the id fields to use why bother with lombok? The blog (which isn't mine!) shows this.

Comment: For #1, we do not have to select all the fields and can select which field we want. Regarding t #3, I am still not sure how to use lombok properly (there are a parameter value in that notation).

Comment: Apparently you haven't read the blog... The `equals` and `hashCode` need to be consistent over entity transitions. So for a JPA managed entity you cannot change any field. So for `equals` use `id` if `id` is `null` objects aren't equal, for `hash` use the `hashCode` of the class (as explained in the blog).

Comment: I know both of 2 points that you mentioned

Comment: Thanks, You have useful suggestions, but your sentences are a little bit confusing, for that reason I am getting confused. As far as I understood, you mean that I can use only id field as id is PK and there is **no need** to use the other unique field (email) in equals() ans hashCode(9 methods. Right?

Comment: That is what I'm saying. The fact that id is unique doesn't mean it couldn't change. The fact that it changes doesn't suddenly make this a different row in the database. If that field is immutable, you could use that in your `equals`/`hashCode` implementation. The important thing is it needs to be something that cannot change.

Comment: Yeah, you right. Actually, I am referring Primary Key for Id and that means it does not changed. Just think the entities you create, assume that there is a PK id field and unique email field. Then, would you use both of them or one of them (which one) in your equals() and hashCode() methods? I just wanted to be clarified about this point?

Comment: Again it doesn't matter if the `email` field is unique... The importance is can it be changed... If you allow someone to change the `email` field you cannot use it. I generally stick with the `id` field for JPA entities, as that will (after assignment) never change.

Comment: Now it is ok, thanks and voted up ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the option that generates fewer code and no need 3rd party libraries. I prefer Java7+. Include just the primary key field because the important thing is to verify if 2 differents instances are representing the same row in database. There's no need to verify if all field values are the same.

You can read more about [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32101614)

Comment: 1. In IntelliJ, when I use "Genarate" feature (via Alt + Insert), there are some templates like IntelliJ Default, Java 7+, etc. Which template should I use? R/ Use the option that generates fewer code and no need 3rd party libraries. I prefer Java7+.

2. When using "Genarate" feature, which field should I include in my equals() and hashCode() methods of the following entity? R/Include just the primary key field because the important thing is to verify if 2 differents instances are representing the same row in database.

@AhmedurRahmanShovon

Comment: @CaptainPsycho can you include this in your answer?

Comment: @CaptainKirk Amigo, do you mean that only adding PK field would be enough by using Java7+ option?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, adding only PK filed is enough. I am adding a link to my answer for better documentation.

Comment: @CaptainPyscho Voted up. But I am confused with *"Unfortunately, we can't use that approach with generated identifiers! Hibernate will only assign identifier values to objects that are persistent, a newly created instance will not have any identifier value!"* in the documentation. Does it mean that we cannot use PK fields before creating the entity? Or what it meaning?

Comment: @Jonathan Problem occurs when you have entities with PK autogenerated (identity column) and only, and only if you have a `Set<>` of those entities that you have not saved in database. Why? beacuse they have not PK value yet. The recommendation in this case is not to use PK field but a ***unique** natural business key*, for example an *email* in an *User* table.

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo. But as far as I see, it is a general situation and we should not use id (PK) field alone in the hash() and equals() method. Right?

Answer (score 5):

One rather crucial issue to consider is what a `User` object represents.

### It represents a row in the database

That means if the `unid` is unset (i.e. you haven't `save()`d it yet) then no 2 user objects can be identical to each other. After all, if you make 2 instances of User, set every value (other than `id` which you don't mess with)  to the same thing, and then save() both, you have 2 rows: Thus proving they aren't identical. However, to stick with java rules, they will be identical if there is reference identity (i.e. `this == other`).

When `unid` *is* set then the only thing that decides whether 2 `User` objects are identical, is if their unid is identical. All other properties are irrelevant - after all, if you query the same DB for the same row (getting a separate `User` instance for each, that have identical values), and then you `setEmail` on one of them, then the `email` field is no longer identical, but it doesn't matter: They refer to the same row, save one and the other changes along, thus, they *are* identical.

Conclusion: Write your own equals method that looks like:

```
if (other == null) return false;
if (other.getClass() != User.class) return false;
if (this == other) return true;
if (this.id == null || other.id == null) return false;
return this.id.equals(other.id);
```

And hashCode can just be `id.hashCode()`, returning `0` or `31` if you prefer (or any other prime, won't make much of a difference in practice) if `id` is null.

### It represents a User

In that case, the fact that you can `save()` them, and that they also have an `id` representing absolutely nothing relevant about the user, just representing an 'implementation detail' of the backing storage system, you would compare everything **except** `id` - Any 2 User object whose name and email are equal, **are equal**, even if the objects happen to represent 2 separate rows (somehow - you have a uniqueness constraint on email. But you can still make that happen - make a new instance that you haven't saved yet, the SQLException won't occur until you save it).

### But those are each others exact opposite!

Yeah. They are. Annoying, isn't it? One checks only `id`, the other checks everything except `id`.

Hibernate/JPA is confused about what it thinks it wants, peddling itself as both a database abstraction (the first 'take') as well as an object persistence framework (which steers much closer to the second case), and thus I still haven't actually seen which of these 2 views is 'preferred' by hibernate.

Hence, uh.. pick one, I guess. I think the first one is far more 'correct' and far more likely to do what you want (keep in mind that hitting every property might cause quite the cascade in selects to fetch all those values, especially if you have interconnected stuff, i.e. references to other tables, that's one of a few reasons why the first view is 'better'), however, in my experience, it's less commonly deployed.

If you want to choose the second option, you can just use lombok's stuff. Make sure to mark `id` with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`. For the first - easier to just write it yourself, see snippet above.

Comment: So, by considering that User is an entity / table, what would you suggest?

Comment: I'd interpret 'entity' as meaning: That it represents an actual User itself. That's the point: You __cannot__ come up with a sane definition of what equals should look like if a single class is to represent both 'a row in the table' as well as 'the thing itself'. You have to pick one - does the `class User` represent the entity, __or__ the table? It cannot represent both.